# How to search a specific string after a specific string found in a file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find a specific set of strings like **Test2**, **Test3** and **Test4** in different lines after searching for another specific patter called **Base** using PowerShell. To make a report of Base, Test2, Test3 and Test4 line contents together, I have written a code as mentioned below:
However, it is not getting me the required output all the time. The file data is like

```
Base: some text
some line here
some line here
Test2: another text 
Test3: other text
Test4: different text
some lines here
some lines here
some lines here
Base: some text
some line here
some line here
Test2: another text 
Test3: other text
Test4: different text
some lines here
some lines here
some lines here
some lines here
.............
.............
```

```
$data = Get-Content $file
$req_data = $data |where {$_.Contains("Base") -or $_.Contains("Test2") -or $_.Contains("Test3") -or $_.Contains("Test4")}
$bases_data = $data |where {$_.Contains("Base")}
foreach ($basedata in $bases_data)
{
   $find_alias = ($req_data |select-string "^${basedata}$" -context (0.10)).Context.PostContext
   $final_data = "" | select Base, Test2, Test3, Test4
   $temp.Base = $basedata
   $temp.Test2 = ($find_alias |select-string "Test2").Tostring()
   $temp.Test3 = ($find_alias |select-string "Test3").Tostring()
   $temp.Test4 = ($find_alias |select-string "Test4").Tostring()
   $temp
}
```

Expected Output should be:

```
Base                Test2                Test3              Test4
Base line data     Test2 line data      Test3 line data     Test4 line data
......             .........            .......             ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is in the file. You can use `Select-String` to pick the corresponding lines for any string.

```
$test_file = Get-Content C:\Informatica_POC\Test_file.txt

$test_file| Select-Object @{name='Base'; Expression={$_ |Select-string 'Base'} },
                          @{name='Test2'; Expression={$_ |Select-string 'Test2'} },
                          @{name='Test3'; Expression={$_ |Select-string 'Test3'} },
                          @{name='Test4'; Expression={$_ |Select-string 'Test4'} }|
                          Format-Table -AutoSize
```

[image]

I have not worked much on the formatting. But that is also doable. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you but the problem here is I want to pick the information from the set of lines that contains Base. Test2, Test3 and Test4 lines exist in multiple lines in the file. However, Base is only limited to specific lines in the file, I want to pick those lines that comes beneath Base patter string. Is that possible ?

Comment: @karthik: Kindly share your sample output so that it is easier to process.

Comment: My file content is as follows:

```
Base: some text
...................................
Test2: another text 
Test3: other text
Test4: different text
...................................
Test2: another text 
Test3: other text
Test4: different text
.........................................
Base: some text
...................................
Test2: another text 
Test3: other text
Test4: different text

```
I am looking to print those lines of Base, Test2, Test3 and Test4 wherever the search finds the pattern Base

Comment: @karthik: Please edit the question and give the proper format